# Workout and Supplments for fast results

Tags: diet, supplements, bellyfat

I got a big day coming up after 13 weeks. I think its plenty of time for me to loose my belly fat, i am 35 inches waist, with a baby bear belly. I resumed gym, after 3 months just 2 days ago and burning 400 cal on tredmill and doing chest, abs (short of mix) exercises everyday. I have removed sugar from my food and bread. So i eat 4-9 eggs (boiled n white part) and rest of day try to eat chicken, lightly fried and from my last instructor what i got supplements list, which are [image: these], having said that someone told me, that is too much of supplements. Which now confuses me, to take or not. As i spend good amount of money, just to add it to my routine to loose belly fat and gain mass.
So my question is, how much should i working out everday and what diet should i take, not that i loss mass, but to loss my belly and have somewhat flat tummy (if not good abs), and what should i be eating and avoiding and if i should continue with supplements? When will i start seeing some results.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand your question, please see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The only things you need on that entire list are fish oil, a good multi vitamin(opti-men is nice but will turn your pee yellow for the first few round abouts), and whey.(not necessary if you eat enough meats, most people use whey out of convenience). BCAAs and glutamine are bro science supplements at best, and also, taking BCAAs with whey(in your intra and post workout)is redundant since most if not all whey powders have the same typical amino acid blend. you do NOT need any of that other junk. just supplement with the necessities in the morning and be done with it, you don't need a schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to note that the word "Supplement" means to supply what the primary food does not.  I agree that you are taking too many supplements, and if you are not careful it will be at a level which might cause detrimental effects.

**Nutrition / Supplementation**

There needs to be a proper balance.  First, let's look at your description of dietary changes:

- Removing sugar: good move.  It provides nothing of value and is just extra calories.
- Removing bread: verdict is out on this one.  A good high fiber bread can be a convenient way to eat lunch on the go without causing too much detriment
- Eating eggs: good move.  They are like nature's multivitamin.  Nothing wrong with 4-9 eggs a day, but you'll have to watch the fat content if you eat the yolk.
- Eating chicken, lightly fried: Not a great move.  Chicken is a great food to eat when you trying to get rid of some fat, but frying it adds fat and if you aren't careful will cause you to have more calories than you think.

The primary goal for your diet is to make sure you are eating good things in the right amounts to achieve your goals.  To lose weight, you need to know roughly how many calories you burn normally.  After that, you adjust by dropping a couple hundred calories at a time until you are losing roughly 1-2 pounds a week.

- Protein should be reasonably high: 1.8g per kg target body weight
- Fat should be at least: .35g per kg target body weight
- Carbohydrates make up the rest.

The number I gave for fat content is the minimum amount to maintain health.  Keep in mind that there is 9 calories for every gram of fat.  Compare that to both protein and carbohydrates which is only 4 calories per gram.  You have to eat the minimum amount of fat your body needs to maintain proper function to burn fat and not muscle.  After that, you have to find the right balance between fat and carbohydrates where you feel satisfied from your food but are still losing weight.

As far as supplements go, you really should keep it simple:

- A sports multivitamin, take the dose on the package (example: Opti-Men by Optimum Nutrition)
- About 3g Omega-3 (look at the package, mg of fish oil is not the same thing)
- If you live outside the tropical belt, Vitamin D3, 2500 IU a day

You can spread the supplements out as you see fit throughout the day.

If you have a hard time getting your protein in while cutting calories, you may consider a whey protein supplement.  Make sure you look at the package so you aren't getting one with lots of sugar or dextrose in it (i.e. not a bulking protein mix).

Above all, get your sleep.  About 8 hours sleep a night will make sure you are burning as much fat as you can while preserving as much muscle as you can.  Not getting enough sleep causes your body to hold on to fat and burn more muscle.

**Training**

Strength training should be about 3 times a week.  If you do about 20 minutes of cardio work per day it should help with health, recovery, and burning fat.  However you do need to challenge yourself during strength training.  If you are beginner, you want to hit the following areas:

- Legs
- Core
- Chest/Arms/Shoulders

A good beginner program would look like this:

*Workout A*

- Squats: 3x8
- Bench: 3x8
- Pull-up/Chin-up: 3xAMAP (as many as possible)

*Workout B*

- Squats: 3x8
- Bench: 3x8
- Deadlift: 1xAMAP

When 3x8 gets too tough to keep adding 5 lbs each time you go in, switch to 5x5, then 3x5, and finally 3x3.

If you aren't used to free weight and feel more comfortable with machines, then swap out squats for leg press and leg curl and add in core specific work.  By working bigger muscles, your body transformation will go better.

Comment: so what should I do on supplements that I m having, although that was given to me after my body assessment by my instructor. He isn't dietriation but a trainer. If I am taking that much, how much I need to intensify my workout? How and when I see the change. My each rep is of 15.

Comment: 15 rep sets are fine, but use the heaviest weight you can muster for 15 reps.  The biggest thing is that full body movements incorporating your largest muscle groups will do the most for body transformation.  Chest is important, but don't neglect the legs (which were conspicuously missing in your description of the program).

Comment: As to the supplements in your possession, you can use them up for now, although I would slow down the Vitamin C to 1000 mg a day.  You'll find that a number of those supplements have minimal effect.  Educate yourself by going to Examine.com and see what the supplement is supposed to do for you and what appropriate dosing should be.

Comment: Those supplements, if taken how much you till i need to workout like how many sets and with each set, how many rep?

Comment: @Nofel, I'm not sure I understand.  Supplements like Vit. C don't correspond to the work you put in.  They help your body function better when it is short on a micronutrient.

Comment: I have a lazy body and routinue, I get fatigued easily and I cannot do more than 3 set each, my question is that if I take those supplements I need to work more than 3 set each? So how much is good to consume what I take. I need to maximize my workout for loosing my belly fat, say in few months. I do however in 2 weeks have seen outcome in my arms as my biceps and tri and whole arm size seem bigger but I hardly see any effect on my belly fat.

Comment: I gave the doses for supplements in my answer.  3 sets of 8 is a lot of work.  Keep at it.  As to the belly fat, be patient.  If your body weight is going down about 1-2 lbs a week you are losing more fat than muscle.  Do you have any estimate on the amount of body fat you are carrying?

Comment: also you mentioned beginner workout, how much sets and rep will be in advance workout?

Comment: Advanced training varies the sets and reps over the space of 1-3 months.  Take a look at routines like Wendler 5-3-1, Juggernaut Training, or the Cube method for examples of what advanced training routines look like.  Guaranteed, you will be putting in more work on an advanced routine than on a beginner routine.